# Routing between two Cisco CSR1000v instances on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cisco, ip-routing, virtual-network

I'm building a lab in AWS with Cisco CSR1000v virtual routers. I've tried both the below options.

- In option 1, there's no way to force the traffic from linux1 or 2 to the respective CSR routers since it's all in the same VPC, so it didn't work. I was able to share routers between the routers to the Linux subnets with RIP but not OSPF (since it uses multicast addressing - not allowed in VPC) [Option1 diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NvL9.png)
- In option 2, I can route traffic from linux through CSR but the CSRs can't share routes over peered VPC, elastic IP or transit gateway... [Option2 diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vcxB.png) - I've followed [this lab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCrr7PvMfkE&t=824s) to achieve this.

Has anyone been able to pull this off? I just need a small lab like this to run some tests.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you following a tutorial or are you making it up yourself? If you're using a tutorial please edit your question to include a link.

Comment: Thanks Tim - it's a bit of both and lots of time experimenting... I've added the link to the lab in the question above for option 2

Answer (score 0):

for the next person stumbling on this, I've found a solution! CSR is a full blown virtual router, so it's a really good way to learn Cisco technology and networking in general.

Because I was deploying in AWS, to get routing protocols working, I had to create a IPSec tunnel first between the two routers and then run EIGRP through them. This is captured well in the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0i25-Dxrcw&t=1366s). If more routes need to be added, a hub/spoke model can also be used - see [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/products/collateral/routers/cloud-services-router-1000v-series/csr-in-aws-cvd.pdf).

Hope it helps!

Comment: This could benefit from having more information in the question itself rather than as links to YouTube or Cisco as links tend to change or disappear. I'm not saying a full transcription and links can be useful but at least a general gist of what's behind the links would be appreciated.